# classification in r neuralnet

Tags: r, neural-network

I'm using `neuralnet` in R to predict 3 classes based on 17 inputs. I have 3 classes: 1, 0 and 2. I have 2 files: training and testing. Training has 64 cases of 17 inputs and 18 column is output.

```
x1              x2              x3          etc...    x17                   y
-0.002307       0.034095    -0.002733            0              1
0.004461       -0.041385     0.137767          -0.294394        0
-0.25254       -0.094523     0                  0.074733        0
-0.25254       -0.094523     0                  0.074733        2
```

and more. 64 rows in total for training.

The test set is exactly same as the training data (16 rows), just with different values.
The code I use

```
library(neuralnet)

nn <- neuralnet(y ~ x1+x2+x3
                  +x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10+x11+x12+x13+x14+x15+x16+x17, 
                data=train,lifesign="full", hidden=15, err.fct="ce", 
                linear.output=FALSE)
an1 <-  compute(nn, Test[1:17])
```

I can do prediction for nn training

```
prediction (nn)
```

Which gives me prediction classes columns y for training case sets but I cannot do same with

```
prediction (an1): error message

Error in matrix(covariate[not.duplicated, ], nrow = nrow.notdupl) : 
  'data' must be of a vector type
```

I'm not entirely sure I need predict, or compute should be enough. But results for compute I get are:

```
$net.result
             [,1]
 [1,] 0.7503498233120
 [2,] 0.9982475522024
....
 [14,] 0.0007727434740
 [15,] 0.9999287879015
```

Which I don't know how to interpret it. I need something  like

```
  2                1            0
  [1,] 0.964182671 0.022183652 0.013633677
  [2,] 0.952685528 0.032202528 0.015111944
  [3,] 0.966094194 0.021206723 0.012699083..
```

with probability distribution to each class.

I tried to use `ifelse`

```
 At2 <-(ifelse(Train$y==2,"2", ifelse(Train$y==1, "1","0")))
```

but still get the same 1 column for `net.result`.

Anyone could help to point out what line am I missing here to get what I want?
Also I think `ifelse` does not do what I want - predict class Y based on 17 inputs. Is it so?

Comment: Interestingly, after scanning the documentation, I don't see a way to calculate predicted values for a test set in that package at all. Maybe try a different neural net implementation?

Comment: What about *compute* and *prediction*? Just give the predictors dataset and is should work...

Comment: @Joran.I was before and I'm looking at package nnet now too and trying it. There is predict function there too. But so far I couldn't get from it what I want to.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get what I want by using nnet package and in particular predict function there.

```
idC <-class.ind(Train$y)
NN1=nnet(Train, idC[Train], size=15, maxit = 200, softmax=TRUE)
predict(NN1, data=Test,type = "class")
```

many thanks for all responses! :)

Answer (score 1):

In the docs is says *compute()* returns a list of results, and *prediction()* takes a neuralnet fitted model...so i guess you're using it the wrong way.

Comment: compute() returns a list of results. What results? Do you mean that by using compute and predict I cannot get neuralnet do what I want to do at all or it is possible to get it with compute and predict but not in the way I use them?